# Text Input Returns "false" Instead of Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var stattrak = self._convertString( $product.find( ".product-etchings" ).val() );
var nametag = self._convertString( $form.find( ".product-nametag" ).val() );
```

The code is set to find those two vars in a form. There are two textbox's one that is the etchings and the other is for a nametag. when I enter in something like 111 into the etchings box, i get a "false" return into the stattrak var. same for the nametag. i have no clue why its doing this...

here is the HTML for the form, sorry.

```
<form class="add-to-cart" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="qty-1">Quantity &nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
        <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" /><br>
        <hr>
        <label for="stattrak">Etchings &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="stattrak" id="stattrak" class="product-etchings" value="none" /><br>
        <hr>
        <label for="nametag">Namtag &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="nametag" id="nametag" class="product-nametag" value="none" /><br><br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-success">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

And then some more of the Javascript:

```
handleAddToCartForm: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$formAddToCart.each(function() {
            var $form = $( this );
            var $product = $form.parent();
            var price = self._convertString( $product.data( "price" ) );
            var name =  $product.data( "name" );

            $form.on( "submit", function() {
                var stattrak = self._convertString( $form.find( "#stattrak" ).val() );
                var nametag = self._convertString( $form.find( "#nametag" ).val() );
                var qty = self._convertString( $form.find( ".qty" ).val() );
                var subTotal = qty * price;
                var total = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.total ) );
                var sTotal = total + subTotal;
                self.storage.setItem( self.total, sTotal );
                var stattrak = self._convertString( $form.find( ".stattrak" ).val() );
                var nametag = self._convertString( $form.find( ".nametag" ).val() );
                self._addToCart({
                    product: name,
                    price: price,
                    qty: qty,
                    stattrak: stattrak,
                    nametag: nametag
                });
                var shipping = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.shippingRates ) );
                var shippingRates = self._calculateShipping( qty );
                var totalShipping = shipping + shippingRates;

                self.storage.setItem( self.shippingRates, totalShipping );
            });
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please provide us with the rest of the HTML/JS code. It is hard to tell what's going on with the small piece of code provided.

Comment: I should also add, the var qty and var total come out correct, with the correct corresponding text field text.

Comment: Where is the definition for the `_convertString()` function?